# How to query firestore in real time in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I have this code

```
  checkUserValue(String user) async {
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await _firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentReference userRef = _firestore
          .collection("users")
          .where("id", isEqualTo: "hhjhgjhfhgfhgfh");
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(userRef);
      String docc = snapshot.get("username");
      print(docc);
      if (docc == null) {
        _userExist = false;
      } else {
        _userExist = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

But am faced with this issue,

[image]

Please I need solution

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

`where(...)` function return `Query<Map<String, dynamic>>` not the `DocumentReference`

You need to pass the document path (DocumentReference) in the `get()` method. So, specify the correct document path

```
  DocumentReference userRef = _firestore.collection('users').doc('hhjhgjhfhgfhgfh');
```

```dart
  checkUserValue(String user) async {
    FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    await _firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {

      DocumentReference userRef =
          _firestore.collection('users').doc('hhjhgjhfhgfhgfh');

      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(userRef);

      String docc = snapshot.get('username');

      print(docc);
      if (docc == null) {
        _userExist = false;
      } else {
        _userExist = true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am searching the documents that's why I used where condition

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? (I mean the purpose of searching documents)?

Comment: where userid == string